# Soundcloud API suddenly started returning 404 when attempting to follow/unfollow valid users

Tags: ruby, soundcloud

Using Soundcloud Ruby gem. Was working fine until a few days ago when attempting to follow or unfollow a valid user returns a 404 error.

IE: client.put("/users/me/followings/[THE USER ID]")
Returns # with a message about a 404 error.

I saw on Soundcloud.com a notice that said something about the followers system being down, so perhaps this is related, but I no longer see that message. What going on? Is the API down? Have there been recent changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this. The issue should be resolved now.

The `v1` endpoints are "legacy", but should work now anyway.

In the future we plan to deprecate and remove support for those.

Comment: Hey @Alon, thanks for the response. It's still giving me the error using the official soundcloud ruby gem. Is there a way to specify the endpoints when using that gem?

Comment: It seems that you're not using the correct endpoint for your request. Please follow the instructions here: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#follow. For example: client.put('/me/followings/3207')

Comment: you are correct. Quite strange as it was working until the recent update. Anyway, I can verify that client.put('/me/followings/3207') now works correctly. Thanks for the fix and the response!

Answer (score 1):

SoundCloud changed followers api URLs recenlty. Earlier followers api url was

```
 https://api.soundcloud.com/v1/me/followings/[THE USER ID]?client_id=[THE CLIENT ID]&app_version=1456328900
```

It changed by

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/me/followings/[THE USER ID]?client_id=[THE CLIENT ID]&app_version=1456328900
```

They remove **V1** from URL.